# Equivalent of Coldfusion's find command in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find a substring in SQL, equivalent to something I have in coldfusion.

I know I can use "substring()" instead of "mid()", what I can I in place of "find()" ?

Comment: Can you give an example? Data and expected results? If you are just trying to find a string in a field, then use `Where columnname Like '%blah%'`

Comment: When looking for a substring pattern within a string, use either `CHARINDEX` or `PATINDEX`. `CHARINDEX` looks for an exact string, while `PATINDEX` has some pattern matching capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CHARINDEX`

Example: try to find 'a' in 'apple'

`CHARINDEX('a','apple',0)` '0' here means the startpoint, if you specified, the default is 0

Comment: And it will only return the first 'a' that after the startpoint, for example: CHARINDEX('a','applea',0) will return 1 which means the first 'a' appears at position 1, if you want to return 6, you have to change the start point which is larger than 1